# Why can't run-time polymorphism be solved at compile time?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Consider:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void show() { cout<<" In Base \n"; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
       void show() { cout<<"In Derived \n"; }
};

int main(void)
{
    Base *bp = new Derived;
    bp->show();  // RUN-TIME POLYMORPHISM
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code cause run-time polymorphism and why can not it be solved at compile time?

Comment: If you want compile time polymorphism, look at the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: Are you asking about this simple case, or the general case?

Comment: The general case is undecidable because it involves solving the Halting Problem (or an equivalent problem, e.g. program equivalence). It also doesn't make sense from a practical point of view because it may depend on runtime information such as user input.

Comment: @Jens when I google why run time polymorphism involves the Halting problem, I get this SO page. Can you provide some more info?

Comment: @Carlos It's not runtime polymorphism in general, but the question if the compiler can figure out statically which method is called even when it does not depend on any runtime information. In this case, it basically comes down Program Equivalence or Reachability, which are both undecidable because of the Halting Problem. In the given example a compiler should have no problem to remove the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @Carlos The pattern of `Base* x = SolveAnUndecidedProblemAndReturnSomeClassInstance();` and then `x->VirtualCall();` is one possible example of the "general case".

Comment: Aha, got it. It's much more general.

Comment: Function overriding is always run-time polymorphism. If there are more than one derived classes then it is almost impossible for compiler to resolve it at compile time.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Because in the general case, it's *impossible* at compile time to determine what type it will be at run time.  Your example can be resolved at compile time (see answer by @Quentin), but cases can be constructed that can't, such as:

```
Base *bp;
if (rand() % 10 < 5)
    bp = new Derived;
else
    bp = new Base;
bp->show(); // only known at run time
```

EDIT: Thanks to @nwp, here's a much better case.  Something like:

```
Base *bp;
char c;
std::cin >> c;
if (c == 'd')
    bp = new Derived;
else
    bp = new Base;
bp->show(); // only known at run time
```

Also, by corollary of [Turing's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), it can be shown that *in the general case* it's mathematically impossible for a C++ compiler to know what a base class pointer points to at run time.

Assume we have a C++ compiler-like function:

```
bool bp_points_to_base(const string& program_file);
```

That takes as its input `program_file`: the name of *any* C++ source-code text file where a pointer `bp` (as in the OP) calls its `virtual` member function `show()`.  And can determine *in the general case* (at sequence point `A` where the `virtual` member function `show()` is first invoked through `bp`): whether the pointer `bp` points to an instance of `Base` or not.

Consider the following fragment of the C++ program "q.cpp":

```
Base *bp;
if (bp_points_to_base("q.cpp")) // invokes bp_points_to_base on itself
    bp = new Derived;
else
    bp = new Base;
bp->show();  // sequence point A
```

Now if `bp_points_to_base` determines that in "q.cpp": `bp` points to an instance of `Base` at `A` then "q.cpp" points `bp` to something else at `A`.  And if it determines that in "q.cpp": `bp` doesn't point to an instance of `Base` at `A`, then "q.cpp" points `bp` to an instance of `Base` at `A`.  This is a contradiction.  So our initial assumption is incorrect.  So `bp_points_to_base` can't be written for *the general case*.

Comment: Maybe reading from `cin` would have been a better example than `rand` since `rand` can be easily precalculated.

Comment: It is also not possible to do this from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: you should see your rand with time , otherwise it is solvable at compile time. True I am being pedantic.

Comment: @g24l: Seeding with time in general is not advisable, especially if using a precision at the second, as an adversary can easily predict the seed and, if knowing the algorithm, from then on reconstruct the list of "random" values. In C++11, using `rand` is ill-advised and the new `<random>` header provides `std::random_device` specifically to get "true" randomness (on Unix, it would probably use `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` as a source of entropy).

Comment: @MatthieuM. true, i totally agree, I just wanted to stress that one has to *seed* with something that it is not compile time known, otherwise it is compile time solvable.

Comment: Guys, @Paul_Evans is not writing crypto here.  Just answering a question about compile-time precalculations!

Comment: The follow-up information can be useful to someone. I, for one, didn't know seeding with time was not advisible (though I always found it to be too easy to be secure :) )

Comment: @loneboat I tip my [hat](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015) to you sir :)))

Comment: Wow, proving things about C++! Turing was sure ahead of his time! =P

Comment: @Mehrdad He most certainly was!  The proof holds because C++ (and hence any C++ compiler which can be written in C++) is [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) :P

Comment: @PaulEvans: Yes I know what you're trying to say, but the statement about C++ is a corollary of what he proved, not what he actually proved... =P

Comment: Re. your last example: that proves that this problem **is not harder** than the halting problem; it doesn't prove it's **at least as hard** which is what you were trying to show.

Comment: @immibis Thanks, removed it from answer accordingly.

Comment: @immibis The proof should be simple: 1. Assume that a Program P1(F, x) that computes the dynamic types in F for input x. 2. Construct a new program P2(F, x) = { struct A {virtual bool f() = 0;}; struct B: public A{bool f() {return true;}}; struct C: public A {bool f() {return false;}; A* a = (H(F,x)) ? (new B) : (new C); return a->f();} where H(F,x) solves the Halting Problem. According to our assumption, we can determine the static type of a and thus P1(P2, x) is computable, but this is equivalent to computing H(F,x). We know that H(F,x) is not computable, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: @Jens You've assumed in your proof that you already have a function that computes the halting problem. You've shown that if you can compute the halting problem, then you can compute the halting problem.

Comment: @Jens By similar reasoning, using `int x = (H(F,x)) ? 1 : 2; return x + 1;` you can "prove" that it's impossible to add two integers. ("... according to our assumption, we can determine the value of `x + 1` and thus `x + 1` is computable, but this is equivalent to computing H(F,x). We know H(F,x) is not computable, so we have a contradiction.")

Comment: @immibis Your function is not f(x)=x+1, but f(F,x). The question is not if f is computable, but if we can write a program that decides if x will be assigned 1 or 2 for any input. The argument is the same as proving that Reachability is not computable. I assume that it is computable, thus I have a program R(F, x, n) which computes if line n of program F is reached with input x. Now, I construct a new program P = `int x; if F(x)  {x =1;} else {x=2;}; return x + 1;`. If Reachability is computable, I can compute G(F, x) = R(P, x, 3), when 3 is the line "x=1", and thus decide the Halting Problem.

Comment: @immibis You are right that H(F,x) should not be used.

Comment: @immibis I think the comment section here is not the right place for sketching the proof, and to discuss it. I will put a sketch somewhere else and come back to you.

Comment: A compiler can still modify this to "if (checkhardproof) { bp = new Derived (); bp->DerivedShow (); } else { bp = new Base (); bp->BaseShow (); }

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks, you're right.  Backed out the 'proof' stuff and stuck with 'show'.

Comment: @PaulEvans Big like for your mention of Turing's Proof!

Answer (score 83):

Compilers routinely devirtualise such calls, when the static type of the object is known. Pasting your code as-is into [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwDwgPYGcAuAnBBDAWwD4AoGdcAcwAIxCF0AHPCBarOAbhJOj3XTUAQvwQlqE6gG8SjGACMoICAC5xk6gDcQ2TDDxQtqEHHYALVAHcAFAEpp1CKhiYkSAETUAkmGGjqADpg7pzUAL4kYdy8UPyCACII2CCaCHAq1HKKyn7oYjJZSqrqRibmVnYOTi5u7j7UicmppkEh4ZHR4JjUBHjg1prGcLYkMhoiedQAVPKM1AC8tAiWDUkpadwaswC0ROgWNrah1AD0J9QASgCqAHLbACpeALIAotQACgDyADIAmk%2BfC7vAASXgAyk8StRcHpsL4AAzcCJAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22clang36x%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O3%20-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%20-Wall%20-pedantic%22%7D%5D%7D) produces the following assembly:

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %rax
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        movl    $.L.str, %esi
        movl    $12, %edx
        callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rdx
        retq

        pushq   %rax
        movl    std::__ioinit, %edi
        callq   std::ios_base::Init::Init()
        movl    std::ios_base::Init::~Init(), %edi
        movl    std::__ioinit, %esi
        movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
        popq    %rax
        jmp     __cxa_atexit            # TAILCALL

.L.str:
        .asciz  "In Derived \n"
```

Even if you cannot read assembly, you can see that only `"In Derived \n"` is present in the executable. Not only has dynamic dispatch been optimized out, so has the whole base class.

Comment: If you want to include only the relevant parts of the assembly, the first 9 lines are the ones that matter.

Answer (score 32):

> Why does this code cause run time polymorphism and why can not it be solved in compile time?

What makes you think that it does?

You are making a common assumption: just because the *language* identifies this case as using run time polymorphism does not mean that an *implementation* is held to dispatching at run time. The C++ Standard has a so-called "as-if" rule: the *observable effects* of the C++ Standard rules are described with regard to an abstract machine, and implementations are free to achieve said observable effects however they wish.

---

Actually, *devirtualization* is the general word used to speak about compiler optimizations aiming at resolving calls to virtual methods at compile-time.

The goal is not so much to shave off the nearly unnoticeable virtual call overhead (if branch prediction works well), it is about removing a black box. The best gains, in terms of optimizations, are keyed on *inlining* the calls: this opens up constant propagation and a whole lot of optimization, and inlining can only be achieved when the body of the function being called is known at compile-time (since it involved removing the call and replacing it by the function body).

Some devirtualization opportunities:

- a call to a `final` method or a `virtual` method of a `final` class are trivially devirtualized
- a call to a `virtual` method of a class defined in an anonymous namespace may be devirtualized if that class is a leaf in the hierarchy
- a call to a `virtual` method via a base class may be devirtualized if the dynamic type of the object can be established at compile time (which is the case of your example, with the construction being in the same function)

For the state of the art, however, you will want to read Honza Hubička's Blog. Honza is a gcc developer and last year he worked on *speculative devirtualization*: the goal is to compute the probabilities of the dynamic type being either A, B or C and then speculatively devirtualize the calls somewhat like transforming:

```
Base& b = ...;
b.call();
```

into:

```
Base& b = ...;
if      (b.vptr == &VTableOfA) { static_cast<A&>(b).call(); }
else if (b.vptr == &VTableOfB) { static_cast<B&>(b).call(); }
else if (b.vptr == &VTableOfC) { static_cast<C&>(b).call(); }
else                           { b.call(); } // virtual call as last resort
```

Honza did a 5-part post:

- [Devirtualization in C++, part 1](http://hubicka.blogspot.fr/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html)
- [Devirtualization in C++, part 2 (low-level middle-end devirtualization by forwarding stores to loads)](http://hubicka.blogspot.fr/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-2-low-level.html)
- [Devirtualization in C++, part 3 (building the type hierarchy)](http://hubicka.blogspot.fr/2014/02/devirtualization-in-c-part-3-building.html)
- [Devirtualization in C++, part 4 (analyzing the type inheritance graph for fun and profit)](http://hubicka.blogspot.fr/2014/02/devirtualization-in-c-part-4-analyzing.html)
- [Devirtualization in C++, part 5 (feedback driven devirtualization)](http://hubicka.blogspot.fr/2014/04/devirtualization-in-c-part-5-feedback.html)

Comment: Aren't most virtual function calls roughly equivalent to the chained if statements you have there anyway (albeit more of a switch/jumptable-type structure)? Or is that just to be able to provide inlined definitions of some of the possibilities?

Comment: @JAB: I am not too aware of the exact hardware cost of "if" vs "switch" (as virtual calls are similar to switches in that multiple targets exist); as you noted though the real gain is that the `static_cast<A&>(b).call();` statement (and its siblings) can be inlined, which in turn opens up a variety of optimizations. Also, note that the reason I mentioned computing the probabilities of getting "A", "B" or "C" is that (1) only those derived classes above a certain probability threshold will appear like so (to avoid bloat) and (2) they can be ordered from the best probability to the worst.

Comment: Indirect branches can have more of an impact on highly pipelined architectures than conditional branches due to branch prediction being trickier to implement, so depending on compiler/optimization level/features supported by the target architecture, some switch statements will indeed get compiled to chained ifs (or some combination of conditionals+jumptables). On the other hand, it's also possible for a compiler to transform a series of chained ifs into a simple indirect branch if the conditions are right.

Comment: @JAB: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It's nice to know that G++ might soon catch up with 1980s Smalltalk technology :-D

Comment: Branching is not necessarily involved : many compilers use the so-called vTable implementation, in which each polymorphic instance contains a pointer to a vTable, which contains a function pointer for each of the different class' functions, at predictable offsets. A virtual call is then performed by accessing the pointer for this function, and calling it.

Comment: @Quentin: A call via a pointer to function is akin to a branch, albeit a multi-target one, similar to a switch statement resolution. In JAB's comment, note the difference between "conditional branch" (`if`) and "indirect branch" (`switch`, virtual-table, ...): modern CPUs support prediction for both idioms, although prediction for the latter (multi-targets) is trickier.

Answer (score 13):

There are many reasons why compilers cannot in general replace the runtime decision with static calls, mostly because it involves information not available at compile time, e.g. configuration or user input. Aside from that, I want to point out two additional reasons why this is not possible in general.

First, the C++ compilation model is based on separate compilation units. When one unit is compiled, the compiler only knows what is defined in the source file(s) being compiled. Consider a compilation unit with a base class and a function taken a reference to the base class:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void polymorphic() = 0;
};
void foo(Base& b) {b.polymorphic();}
```

When compiled separately, the compiler has no knowledge about the types that implement `Base` and thus cannot remove the dynamic dispatch. It also not something we want because we want to able to extend the program with new functionality by implementing the interface. It may be possible to do that at **link time**, but only under the assumption that the program is fully complete. Dynamic libraries can break this assumption, and as can be seen in the following, there will always be cases were it is not possible at all.

A more fundamental reason comes from Computability theory. Even with complete information, it is not possible to define an algorithm that computes if a certain line in a program will be reached or not. If you could you could solve the Halting Problem: for a program `P`, I create a new program `P'` by adding an additional line to the end of `P`. The algorithm would now be able to decide if that line is reached, which solves the Halting Problem.

Being unable to decide in general means that compilers cannot decide which value is assigned to variables in general, e.g.

```
bool someFunction( /* arbitrary parameters */ ) {
     // ...
}

// ...
Base* b = nullptr;
if (someFunction( ... ))
    b = new Derived1();
else
    b = new Derived2();

b->polymorphicFunction();
```

Even when all parameters are known at compile time, it is not possible to prove in general which path through the program will be taken and which static type `b` will have. Approximations can and are made by optimizing compilers, but there are always cases where it does not work.

Having said that, C++ compilers try very hard to remove dynamic dispatch because it opens many other optimization chances mainly from being able to inline and propagate knowledge through the code. If you are interesting, [you can find an interesting serious of blog posts for the GCC](http://hubicka.blogspot.de/2014/04/devirtualization-in-c-part-5-feedback.html) devirtualization implementation.

Answer (score 12):

That could easily be resolved at compile time if the optimizer chose to do so.

The standard specifies the same behavior as if the run-time polymorphism had occurred.  It does not specific that be achieved through actual run-time polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the compiler should be able to figure out that this should not result in runtime polymorphism in your very simple case. Most probably there are compilers that actually do that but that is mostly a conjecture.

The problematic is the General case when you are actually building a complex, and apart of the cases with library dependencies, or complexity of analysing post-compilation multiple compilation units, which would require keeping multiple versions of the same code, which would blow out **AST generation**, the real issue boils down to **decidability** and the halting problem.

> The latter does not permit to solve the problem if a call can be
>   devirtualized in the general case.

The **halting** problem is to decide if a program given an input will halt ( *we say the program-input pair halts*).   It is known that there is no general algorithm , e.g. **a compiler**, that solves for all possible program-input pairs.

In order for the compiler to decide for any program if a call should be made *virtual* or not, it should be able to decide that for all possible program-input pairs.

In order to do that the compiler would need to have an algorithm A that decides that given program P1 and program P2 where P2 makes a virtual call, then program P3 { while( {P1,I} !=  {P2,I} ) } halts for any input I.

Thus the compiler to be able to figure out all possible devirtualization should be able to decide that for any pair (P3,I) over all possible P3 and I;which is undecidable for all because A does not exist. However it can be decided for specific cases that can be eye-balled.

> That is why in your case the call can be devirtualized, but not any
>   case.