# Are there instances where a virtual method call is optimized out?

Tags: c++

For example if `Foo()` is a virtual method of class `Bar`, there are no inheriting classes, and the compiler could deduce at compile-time that the type is `Bar` (eg. `Bar.Foo()`). 
Since it's clear at compile-time that `Bar::Foo()` is the only possible method the call could resolve to, do compilers commonly optimize out the virtual method lookup?

Comment: Surely this is compiler dependent

Comment: This is implementation dependent, but I'm almost sure all reasonable compiler actually do this optimization.

Comment: "there are no inheriting classes" This can almost never be verified.

Comment: [Near-duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34354516/3233393) (it's basically the same question put on its head).

Comment: My experience is that clang and g++ inlines such calls if the type of pointer is a known const.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot yes `final` but I don't see it in the wild much.

Comment: If you expect compiler to know this at compile time then its probably known also to you at write time. So if you want to achive (micro-)optimization by bypassing visrtualization than you could write explicitelly `bar.Bar::Foo();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in such a case `Bar.Foo()` call will be optimized. [Here](http://hubicka.blogspot.ru/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-2-low-level.html) is the explanation of how such a call will be inlined by a GCC compiler.

The whole series of articles from GCC developer Honza Hubička describes how `devirtualization` is implemented on low level and what limitations it has:

- [Devirtualization in C++, part 1](http://hubicka.blogspot.ru/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html)
- [Devirtualization in C++, part 2](http://hubicka.blogspot.ru/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-2-low-level.html)
- [Devirtualization in C++, part 3](http://hubicka.blogspot.ru/2014/02/devirtualization-in-c-part-3-building.html)
- [Devirtualization in C++, part 4](http://hubicka.blogspot.ru/2014/02/devirtualization-in-c-part-4-analyzing.html)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler optimization removing virtual calls is called `devirtualisation`. It requires the compiler to know the exact type of the instance to know that a certain overload is being called.

In the assumption that you have such classes, I would recommend using `final` where useful to indicate that no class can inherit from it, or no inheriting class can override this specific method.

All depends on your compiler, though to a certain extent this is being used already.

A big catch in this optimization is that the compiler needs to know the exact type and can deduce that no classes inherit from it or can override the method call. If the class has a hidden visibility, LTO could find out that a method is only implemented once, however I haven't seen any implementation of that yet.