# Pointer type object in inhertiance

Tags: c++

In this code I am storing the address of object B in pointer type object of A.
If I call the function then the program must run the function of second class but it doesn't work and run function of 1st class.
If I put virtual before the parental class function then it moves towards other class function.
When I stored 2nd class address in pointer type object, program have to show 2nd class function. But it couldn't do this.
Why this is so?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>

class a
{
    public:
    void fun()
    {
       cout << "1st";
    }
};

class b:public a
{
    public:
    void fun()
    {
        cout << "2nd";
    }
};

class c :public a
{
    public:
    void fun()
    {
        cout << "3rd";
    }
};

void main()
{
    a *A;
    b B;
    c C;
    A = &B;
    A->fun();
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `{` while defining `class a`. Hope it is an error in copying and pasting your code to SO and not an error in your actual code.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but you were on the right track with using `virtual`.  If `class a` declares `fun()` to be virtual, then your code should print "2nd" instead of "1st".  Is that the intent?

Comment: All those because of run time polymorphism

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354516/why-cant-run-time-polymorphism-be-solved-at-compile-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i stored 2nd class address in pointer type object, program have to show 2nd class function...

Not, it does not. In C++ functions are associated with classes (types), not objects. So compiler looks at the type of the pointer your functions is called through. Then, it tries to find such function in the corresponding class definition.
In your case compiler sees "call to the function `fun()` through the pointer of type A" and it simply translates it to the address of `fun()` from `class A`.

*The callable function is stored elsewhere, but not inside the object.

Indeed, this is the point of "statically  typed" languages: compiler looks at your object through the prism of the object`s type.

However, as was mentioned, if you want to make association of a function with particular object, you need to use the keyword `virtual`. This will create a virtual table for each object of class A (and all inherited from A). Then addresses of all functions marked is `virtual` will be stored inside this virtual table. Consequently, when inheriting class has its own implementation of a virtual function, the address of the new implementation will `override` the previous address inside the object`s virtual table.

Now, when you call `fun()` through the pointer of `class A` the control flow (now during the runtime) will make a lookup to the objects virtual table and will find an address to the function you expect.

```
class A
{
public:
      virtual void fun()
      {
         cout << "1st";
      }
};
class B
{
public:
      void func() override
      {
         cout << "2nd";
      }
}
void main()
{
    a *A;
    b B;
    A = &B;
    A->fun();  // -> "2nd" 
   // function address deduced at runtime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `virtual` keyword, otherwise inheritance might not work as you expected.

So change your `class a` as follows:

```
class a
{
public:
      virtual void fun()
{
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++, pointers are static. This means that they are always looking for the parent's functions, even if they are pointing to a child class. You can avoid this by declaring a:fun as **virtual**. Take a look at this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/